# How to control Flash slider bar with input text and vice versa in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, slider

This link will show you what I'm trying to do, but in AS3 and with additional features I've described below:
http://www.kirupa.com/developer/mx/slider.htm

1. Sliders will have different max and min values (5-100, 0-80, etc)
2. Need to be able to modify the text in the dynamic box, which also manipulates the slider. For instance, I'd like to be able to drag the slider to, say, 12 and then type in 25 on the box and the slider moves to 25.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The AS3 [Slider Class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/Slider.html) will help you with this - you can set the maximum, minimum and value.

There's an example [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/Slider.html#includeExamplesSummary).